# A man is converting to Islam for me but I don't like him

Tags: halal-haram, conversion, love, helping

So at work there is this guy that I work with. We have been working together for years. Last year he proposed to me. I didn't want to hurt his feelings so I said that the reason I didn't say yes was because he wasn't Muslim. Other then the fact that is true, I really don't like him that way. Then about a month ago he brought in many Quran books and put them on his desk and said that he is learning about Islam. I was very happy that someone was interested in reading and learning more about the religion, but then about a week ago he said, "Now that I'm converting to Islam we can get married". I didn't know how to react so I smiled, nodded and walked away. I know it's wrong to not tell him, but I don't know how. And I don't even know if he believes in Islam at all, or if it is just for the marriage. I need help, What do I do?... I want him to convert, but I don't want to be stuck with him for the rest of my life. How should I tell him, but still make sure he will convert.

Comment: If you don't like him don't marry him. If his conversion was for the sake of Allah he will remain on the right path and you will gain reward for guiding him. If his conversion was an act that will wane when you reject him then Allah does not require his conversion and you don't deserve such a hypocrite either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this man doesn't know you enough to ask you for marriage in the first place, so you should not lead him on or let him believe he has a chance when he does not. If you cannot face him at least write him a letter or something. But try to be gentle because you don't want to stop him from converting. Tell him how you feel don't hold back, you'll just make it harder.